# Mutiple views on the same page, without using routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page where a user can sort some items by some different filters.

In the `Newest` filter, the items will just be listed with a name. However, in the `By collection` filter, items in a certain collection will be underneath the title of the collection.

So, this is two different ways to display the items. I am already handling routes using my backend framework.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: **For which purpose do you want to use Angular then?** I quote "content from a hidden div". You use angular when you want to populate a DOM element with information from a controller $scope, can be achieved without using routing, that's separate.

Comment: You generate some content/results in a controller and output it in each tab you want - from the controller: `$scope.mycontent=[etc]` and in the page {{mycontent}}, but this is kind of defeating the purpose of using Angular.

Comment: I am sorry for the vague question. I have redefined it, please look at the new version. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'm assuming that the data you are receiving has all these attributes:

- DATE
- COLLECTION NAME
- Nr.of LIKES
- ALL

First read this, it's a short documentation on filters Take a look at this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter.

You can make 4 buttons with different orderBy methods.

Here's a JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z6bQN/

You get all the data out then within each tab you manipulate it using `orderBy`

Here is also a working plnkr with the buttons http://plnkr.co/edit/fMrhagVKl2nehzTOHriF

Enjoy.